# node.js Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND making http request in chroot jail

Tags: node.js, chroot

I'm trying to execute a node.js child process in a chroot jail to prevent it from accessing the filesystem outside of its directory.

However, when I do this, the application can no longer make http requests via the 'request' module.  Any request I make ends in the 'Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND'.

There is one issue that was closed in the node.js project that seems to suggest you need to replace the implementation of dns.lookup or copy /etc/resolv.conf into the jail (neither worked for me): https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3399

There is also a Google groups thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/Qb_LMLulZS4

This seems to recommend that you should "put the bind libraries and all its dependencies also into the jail."  I don't understand that statement.

Anyone gotten this to work correctly that could share what they did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is not answer your question but i want to provide results of my research.

```
var ls = require('child_process').spawn('chroot', ['/mnt/chroot/wheezy-chroot', 'node', '/root/simple-server.js']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

This script works properly -- simple-server.js listen and answer post queries as it should to so I want to ask: how do you create your chroot environment? I've created mine with `debootstrap` utility from Debian:

```
cd /mnt/chroot/
debootstrap wheezy ./wheezy-chroot http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian
cd wheezy-chroot
```

then `mount` proc, sys and dev as usual:

```
mount -t proc none proc
mount --rbind /dev dev
mount --rbind /sys sys
```

and also I mount `/usr/local/` to get access to `node`. I suggest that "put the bind libraries and all its dependencies also into the jail." statement means to mount all things you need e.g. `mount -o bind /usr/local /mnt/chroot/wheezy-chroot/usr/local` in my case.

In case I'm completly missed with my answer i'll leave this link: https://github.com/magne4000/node-jail -- may be you find this package usefull.

And the last thing: as far as I know `chroot` is not safe solution in some cases(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot#Limitations). May be you should have a look at such mechanisms like FreeBSD Jail or even LXC.

Comment: Thanks @zarkone! Any chance you could give more details (line by line) how you used debootstrap and mount for proc/sys/dev?

Comment: `var request = require('request'),
    postRequest = request.post('http://www.google.com', {form: { key: 'val'}});

process.stdin.pipe(postRequest).pipe(process.stdout);`
this code works, i've got the result from chroot

Comment: Thanks zarkone - this was the hint I needed.  For future readers, around my specific need to simply have DNS name lookup work, I found I could simply the solution to just mounting '/etc', '/lib', and '/usr/local' in the chroot jail. zarkone's solution of using debootstrap is a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about chroot in child process.

But for using the chroot npm package, I found that if I did a `dns.lookup()` just before chroot, dns lookup would work well even after chroot.

`dns.lookup()` will load the necessary libraries for `getaddrinfo()` call into memory before chroot.